# Vertical align within a bootstrap card header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use boostrap4 in order to create a card header where the title is text-align center of the card-header, an icone that is right align
and both vertically center middle

I tried some things but nothing seems to get to what I want;

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                                                    +
+                        title                  icone+
+                                                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

code:

```
<div class="card-header text-center bg-dark text-white">
            <div class="row h-100">
              <div class="col-md-11">
                <h5>Complete models list</h5>
              </div>
              <div class=col-md-1>
                <i class="far fa-question-circle float-right align-self-center"></i>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
```

any idea how to make it work ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `align-items-center` on the `row`...

```
 <div class="card-header text-center bg-dark text-white">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
             <div class="col-md-11">
                    <h5>Complete models list</h5>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-1">
                   <i class="fa fa-question-circle float-right"></i>
             </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

**Or,** to dead center the `<h5>` while keeping the icon right aligned, use a `d-flex align-items-center` div with auto-margins (`ml-auto`) to push the icon to the right...

```
<div class="card">
       <div class="card-header text-center bg-dark text-white">
             <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                  <h5 class="mx-auto w-100">Complete models list</h5>
                  <i class="fa fa-question-circle ml-auto"></i>
             </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card-body">
             <p class="text-center">center</p>
       </div>
 </div>
```

[Demo of both options](https://www.codeply.com/go/xhcsx5kMNm)

Comment: Hi Thx for your answer ;) I there a way to have my title align center of the all col and not of the col-11?